# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0 when deploying to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-deployment, django-deployment

I tried to deploy my simple django project on heroku, but i couldn't understand how to solve this problem

This is the **`git push heroku master`**

```
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136/vendor/runtime-fixer", line 8, in <module>
remote:     r = f.read().strip()
remote:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
remote:     (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
remote: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
remote: /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136/bin/steps/python: line 5: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
remote: ) is not available for this stack (heroku-20).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 898dd95ff261fc77ac4dcd00edd162d7b7c054f2
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 898dd95ff261fc77ac4dcd00edd162d7b7c054f2
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to portfolio-project10.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/portfolio-project10.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/portfolio-project10.git'

C:...\portfolio-project>
```

It would be very nice if anyone could help me with this, or even recommending an other way to deploy django projects for free

Comment: I think you have not added remote location name
Try using https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Comment: @AakashYadav, nope, this is part of what the Heroku remote outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That entire traceback is inside these parentheses: `() is not available for this stack`. That is the message shown when you request a Python runtime that isn't available. In this case, it looks like your [`runtime.txt`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#specifying-a-python-version) can't even be read due to an unexpected encoding.

Delete it, then create a new file containing something like

```
python-3.10.2
```

only. Make sure it is UTF-8 encoded, commit, and redeploy.

At the moment, these are the currently supported Python versions, but [the list changes as new versions are released](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes):

- `python-3.10.2`
- `python-3.9.10`
- `python-3.8.12`
- `python-3.7.12`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when i was deploying my django application to Heroku. The issue is because of encoding error. Heroku is expecting the file to be saved with utf-8 but I realised that my file was saved with utf-16 le.

So if you are working in vscode then i would suggest to check the encoding for the runtime file at the bottom of vscode

If you click on utf-8 you will get the option of saving the file with different encoding .
Otherwise you can also save the file in notepad. Default encoding used by notepad is utf-8 only

That will work for sure.

Check for other files encoding also if this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I have solved this problem a long time ago, but thank you very much for this tip it might help me in the future

Answer (score 0):

very simple
just delete the runtime.txt and push the code
this worked for me .
thankyou